# setState from .map inside componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to find a solution to using `setState` on mapped items inside `componentDidMount`.

I am using [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/) along with [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) with many `data` items returned but require that on specific `pathname` is `===` to `slug` the `state` is updated in the component to the matching `littleHotelierId`.

```
propertyInit = () => {
  const pathname = location.pathname;
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query {
          allContentfulProperties {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                slug
                information {
                  littleHotelierId
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
     `}
      render={data => {
        data.allContentfulProperties.edges.map(({ node: property }) => {
          if (pathname === property.slug) {
            !this.isCancelled &&
              this.setState({
                littleHotelierId: property.information.littleHotelierId
              });
          }
          return null;
        });
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Then I am pulling this into `componentDidMount` as

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.propertyInit();
}
```

not relevant but as reference `this.isCancelled = true;` is added to `componentWillUnmount`.

I don't receive any errors but if I `console.log(littleHotelierId)` I get nothing.

I did at first think that it may be because `return` is null so tried giving the `map` a `const` and returning as

```
render={data => {
  data.allContentfulProperties.edges.map(({ node: property }) => {
    if (pathname === property.slug) {
      const littleHotelier =
        !this.isCancelled &&
        this.setState({
          littleHotelierId: property.information.littleHotelierId
        });
      return littleHotelier;
    }
  });
}}
```

but this was unsuccessful too.

The Goal is for `componentDidMount` to map items returned in the GraphQL `data` as

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (path1 === '/path-slug1') {
    !this.isCancelled &&
      this.setState({
        littleHotelierId: 'path-id-1'
    });
  }
  if (path2 === '/path-slug2') {
    !this.isCancelled &&
      this.setState({
        littleHotelierId: 'path-id-2'
    });
  }
  ... // other items
}
```

I think the issue is that GraphQL is fetching data as asynchronous and this request not completed as componentDidMount() is called. If I `console.log` the `data` it is not returning anything to the `console`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create some filtered data as a result of a map function. After you have filtered data you do setState({data: data}). It is not good to do multiple setState.

If your GraphQL returns promise then you can write something like the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData()
    .then(data => {
       const filteredData = data.filter(element => 
         element.someProperty === propertyValue
       );
     this.setState({ data: filteredData });
    })
}
```

Comment: `filter` was exactly right for what I needed. Cheers.